# smart contract information issue

Tags: contract-debugging, bytecode, staking, uint256, user-safety

Hi I was scammed by troncase, I want to know how to get my original staking out of the smart contract. it is asking me for a userAddress_address,  last_uint256,  first_uint256 What do i type in those areas. the staking was 108712.2709

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly read the contract code which I've found on tronscan [here](https://tronscan.org/#/contract/TLX771cbbQTWKdKpkg6QvX51P5oNFBA11x/code).
The first value is obvious, it is your address. The 2nd is 0, this is corresponding to your first deposit as all elements are indexing from 0, the 3rd one is the total number of times you deposited minus 1.